# my cropped image is just a black colored box of 2KB?

Tags: php, jcrop

Im using the following `PHP` code to save a cropped image from `jcrop`.

```
$targ_w = $targ_h = 150;
$jpeg_quality = 90;

$src = "../profiles/";
$src = $target . basename( $_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
$dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
$targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);


imagejpeg($dst_r, "simple2.jpg", $jpeg_quality);
```

A `simple2.jpg` does get saved in the directory, but it is just a black colored square of size 2 KB.  I want the cropped part to be saved. How to fix this?

Comment: Please show your POST variables`s values.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

index.php

```
<html lang="en" >
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="author" content="Script Tutorials" />
        <title>HTML5 Image uploader with Jcrop | Script Tutorials</title>

        <!-- add styles -->
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/jquery.Jcrop.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <!-- add scripts -->
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.Jcrop.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <h2>HTML5 Image uploader with Jcrop </h2>
        </header>

        <div class="demo">
            <div class="bheader"><h2>-- Image upload form --</h2></div>

            <div class="bbody">
                <!-- upload form -->
                <form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php" onsubmit="return checkForm()">

                    <!-- hidden crop params -->
                    <input type="hidden" id="x1" name="x1" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="y1" name="y1" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="x2" name="x2" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="y2" name="y2" />


                    <h2>Step1: Please select image file</h2>
                    <div>
                   <input type="file" name="image_file" id="image_file" onchange="fileSelectHandler()" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="error"></div>



                    <div class="step2">
                        <h2>Step2: Please select a crop region</h2>
                        <img id="preview" />

                        <div class="info">
                            <label>File size</label>
                            <input type="text" id="filesize" name="filesize" />

                            <label>Type</label> 
                            <input type="text" id="filetype" name="filetype" />

                            <label>Image dimension</label> 
                            <input type="text" id="filedim" name="filedim" />
                            <label>W</label> <input type="text" id="w" name="w" />
                            <label>H</label> <input type="text" id="h" name="h" />
                        </div>

                        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
                    </div>





                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
function uploadImageFile() { // Note: GD library is required for this function

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
       // $iWidth = $iHeight = 200; // desired image result dimensions

        $iWidth=abs($_POST['x2']-$_POST['x1']);
        $iHeight=abs($_POST['y2']-$_POST['y1']);



        $iJpgQuality = 90;

        if ($_FILES) {

            // if no errors and size less than 250kb
            if (! $_FILES['image_file']['error'] && $_FILES['image_file']['size'] < 250 * 1024)             {
                if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'])) {

                    // new unique filename
                    $sTempFileName = 'cache/' . md5(time().rand());

                //  mkdir("cache",0664,true);
                    chmod('cache', 0664);

                    //echo $url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . dirname(__FILE__);
                    //echo '<br>';
                    $root=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];


                    $newsTempFileName = $root.'/beta/nikhil/demo/jquery-images-direct-crop/'.$sTempFileName;





                    // move uploaded file into cache folder
                     move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'], $newsTempFileName);



                    // change file permission to 644
                    @chmod($sTempFileName, 0644);



                    if (file_exists($sTempFileName) && filesize($sTempFileName) > 0) {
                        $aSize = getimagesize($sTempFileName); // try to obtain image info
                        if (!$aSize) {
                            @unlink($sTempFileName);
                            return;
                        }



                        // check for image type
                        switch($aSize[2]) {
                            case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                                $sExt = '.jpg';

                                // create a new image from file 
                                $vImg = @imagecreatefromjpeg($sTempFileName);
                                break;
                            case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                                $sExt = '.png';

                                // create a new image from file 
                                $vImg = @imagecreatefrompng($sTempFileName);
                                break;
                            default:
                                @unlink($sTempFileName);
                                return;
                        }

                        // create a new true color image
                        $vDstImg = @imagecreatetruecolor( $iWidth, $iHeight );

                        // copy and resize part of an image with resampling
                        imagecopyresampled($vDstImg, $vImg, 0, 0, (int)$_POST['x1'], (int)$_POST['y1'], $iWidth, $iHeight, (int)$_POST['w'], (int)$_POST['h']);

                        // define a result image filename
                        $sResultFileName = $sTempFileName . $sExt;

                        // output image to file
                        imagejpeg($vDstImg, $sResultFileName, $iJpgQuality);
                        @unlink($sTempFileName);

                        return $sResultFileName;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

$sImage = uploadImageFile();
echo '<img src="'.$sImage.'" />';
?>
```

Live Demo : https://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/316/index.html
add jquery and css

Comment: I'm getting the same error. I feel like I'm doing some stupid mistake :(

Comment: Ok i resolved it. In my html, where the image loads, I had specified the dimensions as 200*200. Hence the problem. This code works only when the full image is loaded. I think I need to resize it first.

Comment: please check demo and there is script, there is option, you can do 200*200 max size also min size option